# mongodump and then remove: Not exact same number of records

Tags: python, mongodb, fabric, mongodump

I am using a fabric script to dump data from a remote mongodb server to my local machine and then I wish to remove that data from the remote machine. I am doing it in two steps now and although I can understand that there may be more graceful methods exist for few more days I want to continue like this. 
Here is the snippet of the python function that I run as fab task

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

def dump_mydb():
    print "********************************"
    print "Starting the dump process"
    print "********************************"
    d = datetime.datetime.today()
    d2 = d - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    end_date = datetime.datetime(d2.year, d2.month, d2.day)
    print end_date
    before_time = int(end_date.strftime("%s")) * 1000 

    temp = datetime.datetime.today()
    temp2 = datetime.datetime(temp.year, temp.month, temp.day)
    local_folder = str(temp2).split(" ")[0]
    local("mongodump --host x.x.x.x --port 27017 --collection my_collection --db my_db -q '{fetched_date :{$lte: Date(" + str(before_time) + ")}}'")
    local("mkdir ../dump_files/store/" + local_folder)
    local("cp -r dump ../dump_files/store/" + local_folder)
    local("rm -rf dump")
    print "********************************"
    print "Data before one month from today is dumped at - ../dump_files/store/" + local_folder
    print "********************************"
```

If this script being executed today (14th Feb, 2014, IST) then it searches for all the documents which has "fetched_date" (a normal ISODate object with date and time both present) less than equal to 2014-01-14 00:00:00. And this scripts executes fine.

---

The problem

---

When this script is executed, we can see that it dumps X number of objects (Documents) into my local machine. But when we run this query in the remote mongo shell

```
{"fetched_date":{"$lte": ISODate("2014-01-14T00:00:00.00Z")}}
```

This gives us a different number of records. which is more than X. So that means we can not delete all the records which match this query because some of them did not get dumped in my local machine. I do not understand how is that possible as I am converting the same date in ms and then running the query at mongodump.

Can anybody help me out please?

Please let me know if you need any more information. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you've hit the same issue I did, where db.collection.find({...}).count() can over-count. According to the details in the reference documentation for [count()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#behavior), if you're on a sharded cluster, records being migrated are double-counted. (Thanks GothAlice on the IRC channel for pointing this out to me!)

If this is your issue, you can use the aggregation framework to get an accurate count, which should match the count you saw from mongodump:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      { $match: {"fetched_date":{"$lte": ISODate("2014-01-14T00:00:00.00Z")}} },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

Comment: Counting records in a database is hard to do both accurately and quickly.  Shortcuts are taken, and these shortcuts can indeed produce erroneous counts.  In the sharding case, the count will be equal to or higher then the actual number of records.  In other situations (for example, with in-progress multi-updates or multi-removes) the count may be wrong in different ways.  The given aggregate will be accurate, but only if the data is at rest (no updates/inserts).